# “Unable to locate adb” bug via Intellij Idea Community

Tags: android, intellij-idea, adb, bug

I use IntelliJ Idea Community for automation testing over Appium. I do not need Android Studio for this. The emulator **starts** but I get the message **AVD Manager - Unable to locate adb** I want to resolve this error message.
When I enter in cmd **adb --version** I get:

```
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 30.0.5-6877874
Installed as C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
```

I added the next paths in the Win10 environment

User variable:

```
ANDROID_HOME
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

Path in System variable:

```
    %ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
    %ANDROID_HOME%\tools
    %ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin
```

I tried first to run **adb start-server** but I get the same error message.

I have installed SDK over IntelliJ and JDK is 1.8.0_271

Similar questions did not help me.

---

**edit:**

The same error message I get in Android Studio too.